# break row from specific td to next line

Tags: html, css

I have a table in which `<td>` are coming dynamically and some `<td>` will come with specific class on which the row should break and other `<td>` should start from next line.

As the `<td>` are coming dynamically i can't create another `<tr>` i want to break it with css.

I have seen other examples on stackoverflow but they are showing breaking all the `<td>` to next line but i want to break from specific `<td>` and all then other `<td>` in continuation from this `<td>`

```css
td.break {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td class="break">hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td class="break">hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I tried using `display:block` but its not working if appying on single `<td>`.

Comment: Tables don't work as you imagine, you need to change your markup to divs and play with display inline-block and block. Tables have its own display (table, table-row, table-cell, etc)

Comment: Instead of all this of <td>, you can wrap it under multiple <tr>

Comment: I dont think their is any solution for it using css try using jquery to catch td with class break and append html </tr><tr> before it

Comment: if you can break it with `display:block` on all `<td>` then their must be a solution for single `<td>`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well thanks to Hidden Hobbes after his answer i found a way to do it.

May be its not that prominent code but yes its working absolutely fine.

Using `display:block` in `<tr>` and `float:left` in `.break`

```css
tr {
  display: block
}
td.break {
  float: left;
  line-height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td class="break">hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td class="break">hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
    <td>hdv</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

A little `line-height` is managed as we use `float:left`